# C++ , Array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I was just curious to know how to create an array of strings.
I am looking to make an array of 10 strings and each string can have 20 characters.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   char a[10] , str[20];
    for (int x = 0 ; x<10 ; x++)
   {
    for (int y = 0 ;y<20; y++ )
      {
         cout<<"String:";
         cin>>str[y];
         a[x]=str[y];
      }
   }
   for (int j = 0 ; j<10 ; j++)
    cout<<a[j]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*Newbie in C++ with an open mind :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing is more C approach. 
Anyway:

```
char strings[10][20];

//Accessing each string
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //Accessing each character
    for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    { 
        char character = strings[i][j];
    }
}
```

In c++ you would rather use:

```
std::string strings[10];
```

Or the best option is:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings(10);
```

in c++ 11 you can iterate over last case like this:

```
for(auto singleString : strings)
{

}
```

Comment: is the strings variable in your program a 2D array? i am a noob in programming , just looking for some extra info.

Comment: In the first code quote it's just 2D array of "char" types.

Answer (score 4):

How about instead you use a

```
std::vector<std::string> my_strings(10);  // vector of 10 strings
```

You will have a much easier time this way than statically-size `char` arrays.

You then get all the features of the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container, including dynamic size.

You also get all the nice features of the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class.

Answer (score 0):

In order of preference:

A vector of 10 strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> aVector(10);
```

An array of 10 strings:

```
std::string anArray[10];
```

If you really want to use zero-terminated C strings:

```
typedef char MyString[21];  // 20 + 1, for the terminating zero
MyString arrayOfThem[10];
```

or, the more cryptic variant

```
char anArray[10][21];
```